# xmlhttprequest does not work properly in function

Tags: php, ajax, html, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

is anyone know why upload.onprogress does not work correctly if it's on separate function?

Code work properly (the progress bar slowly moving):

```
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                progress.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            }
        };
```

but if I put it into function, it does not work anymore:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = uploadProgress(event);

function uploadProgress(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        progress.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    }
}
```

On the second code, the progress bar directly jump into 100% after file finished uploaded instead of, move nicely into 100% during the upload

---

so, I've tried the solution provided, it actually work, if I put the function inside. Is there no way to put it outside the function?

```
        function uploadFile(blobFile, fileName) {
            ...
            ...

            // Listen to the upload progress for each upload.
            xhr.upload.onprogress = uploadProgress;

            // Progress Bar Calculation why it has to be in uploadFile function..
            function uploadProgress(e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    progress.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                }
            }                            

            uploaders.push(xhr);
            xhr.send(fd);
        }  

        //it does not work if I put it outside the function. is there anyway to do this?  
        function uploadProgress(e) {
             if (e.lengthComputable) {
                 progress.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `uploadProgress(event);` you call the function itself and assign the return value to `xhr.upload.onprogress` instead of assigning it as a callback function:

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = uploadProgress;
```

Comment: You were right.. variable progress is inside the uploadFile(). That's why it does not work. Is there any good practice in javascript, rather than make it as a function inside of a function.. that would look awful somehow. because 
var progress = document.createElement('progress'); 
should be inside uploadFile() so it produce several progress bar everytime it got called. Thus I can't make it global var

Comment: @user1096900 You could use an anonymous function: `xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e){}` or just an anonymous wrapper function: `xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e){ uploadProgress(e, progress);}`.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example you should use

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = uploadProgress;
```

not

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = uploadProgress(event);
```

You've assigned the result of calling the function, rather than a reference to the function.

Comment: @ComFreek I tried that but it still does not work correctly. It still directly jump to 100% after it finished uploading each chunk.

Comment: place the xhr.upload.onprogress line after the function, hoisting may be a factor in your code.

Comment: @ComFreek, please see my updated  code. so, is there anyway to put it outside the function? or it's just not possible? Thank you

Comment: @user1096900 Please comment on my answer otherwise I don't get any notifications. Are you sure that the variable `progress` is available outside the function `uploadFile` or is it just a local variable?

Answer (score 1):

How about defining the function before assigning as callback?
JavasCript sometimes has problems when defining functions later.

I mean you can replace:

```
// Listen to the upload progress for each upload.
xhr.upload.onprogress = uploadProgress;

// Progress Bar Calculation
function uploadProgress(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
         progress.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    }
}
```

with

```
// Progress Bar Calculation
function uploadProgress(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
         progress.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    }
}
// Listen to the upload progress for each upload.
xhr.upload.onprogress = uploadProgress;
```