# Why might XMLHttpRequest ProgressEvent.lengthComputable be false?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to implement a upload progress bar the HTML5 way, by using the XMLHttpRequest level 2 support for progress events.

In every example you see, the method is to add an event listener to the progress event like so:

```
req.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = Math.round(event.loaded * 100 / event.total);
        console.log(percentComplete);
    }
}, false);
```

Such examples always seem to assume that event.lengthComputable will be true. After all, the browser knows the length of the request it's sending, surely?

No matter what I do, event.lengthComputable is false. I've tested this in Safari 5.1.7 and Firefox 12, both on OSX.

My site is built using Django, and I get the same problem on my dev and production setups.

The full code I'm using to generate the form upload is shown below (using jQuery):

```
form.submit(function() {
    // Compile the data.
    var data = form.serializeArray();
    data.splice(0, 0, {
        name: "file",
        value: form.find("#id_file").get(0).files[0]
    });
    // Create the form data.
    var fd = new FormData();
    $.each(data, function(_, item) {
        fd.append(item.name, item.value);
    });
    // Submit the data.
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = Math.round(event.loaded * 100 / event.total);
            console.log(percentComplete);
        }
    }, false);
    req.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(event.target.responseText);
            if (data.success) {
                console.log("It worked!")
            } else {
                console.log("It failed!")
            }
        } else {
            console.log("It went really wrong!")
        }
    }, false);
    req.addEventListener("error", function() {
        console.log("It went really really wrong!")
    }, false);
    req.open("POST", "/my-bar/media/add/");
    req.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    req.send(fd);
    // Don't really submit!
    return false;
});
```

I've been tearing my hair out for hours on this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I encountered this problem, too. It seems that FormData() makes lengthComputable==false.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Hey I found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9707877/41948) from @ComFreek:

I made the same mistake.

The line I wrote was:

```
xhr.onprogress = uploadProgress;
```

The correct one should be

```
xhr.upload.onprogress = uploadProgress;
```

Comment: ya my hero, but I should read more properly that I would have knew it before :D

Answer (score 1):

take a look into this :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(e){}) will also work.

Answer (score 1):

I also had problem with sending multiple big files using AJAX (xmlhttprequest).

Found a solution and here is whole script that I use.
All you need is to place next line in your HTML page:

```
<input type="file" multiple name="file" id="upload_file" onchange="handleFiles(this)">
```

and use next script:

```
<script type="text/javacript">
    var filesArray;
    function sendFile(file)
    {
        var uri = "<URL TO PHP FILE>";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();

        var self = this;

        xhr.upload.onprogress = updateProgress;
        xhr.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", transferFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                alert(xhr.responseText); // handle response.
            }
        };
        fd.append('myFile', file);
        // Initiate a multipart/form-data upload
        xhr.send(fd);
    }
    function updateProgress (oEvent)
    {
        if (oEvent.lengthComputable)
        {
            var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;
            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete*100) + "%");
        } else {
            // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
            console.log("Total size is unknown...");
        }
    }

    function transferComplete(evt)
    {
        alert("The transfer is complete.");
    }

    function transferFailed(evt)
    {
        alert("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
    }

    function transferCanceled(evt)
    {
        alert("The transfer has been canceled by the user.");
    }
    function handleFiles(element)
    {
        filesArray = element.files;
        if (filesArray.length > 0)
        {
            for (var i=0; i<filesArray.length; i++)
            {
                sendFile(filesArray[i]);
            }
            filesArray = '';
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Your result will be in console