# Showing download progress percentage for JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.udacity.com/public-api/v0/courses',
    xhr: function () {
        console.log('xhr');
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener('loadend', uploadComplete, false);

        function uploadComplete(event) {
            console.log('uploadComplete');
        }
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            console.log(evt.percentComplete);
            console.log([evt.lengthComputable, evt.loaded, evt.total]);
            // if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
            console.log(percentComplete + "p")
            //}
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("success")
    }
});
```

For the above code, the output I'm getting in console is as below:

```
script.js:15 [false, 22463, 0]
script.js:18 Infinityp
script.js:14 undefined
script.js:15 [false, 53062, 0]
script.js:18 Infinityp
script.js:14 undefined
script.js:15 [false, 85830, 0]
script.js:18 Infinityp
script.js:14 undefined
script.js:15 [false, 124733, 0]
script.js:18 Infinityp
script.js:14 undefined
......
```

Why evt.lengthComputable is showing as false and evt.total is showing as 0 ?
P.S : The URL has content-length header.

Is there any other way to track the real time download progress for JSON data?

Comment: "The *URL* has content-length header" - it's not supposed to be in the "url".  How are you specifying the content-length?

Comment: That URL has content-length header. I thought that evt.total will automatically pick from the content-length header. How to specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707839/xmlhttprequest-does-not-work-properly-in-function/9707877#9707877) you should add the `eventlisteners` to the `upload` property of the xhr object. So your code should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.udacity.com/public-api/v0/courses',
    xhr: function () {
        console.log('xhr');
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('loadend', uploadComplete, false); // <-- CHANGED LINE

        function uploadComplete(event) {
            console.log('uploadComplete');
        }
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) { // <-- CHANGED LINE
            console.log(evt.percentComplete);
            console.log([evt.lengthComputable, evt.loaded, evt.total]);
            var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100;
            console.log(percentComplete + "p")
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("success")
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try this code?  I tried it and the percentComplete are not showing on console.  I'm just getting xhr and success message.

Comment: xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) this line should changed to xhr.addEventListener("progress",function(evt)